# How do I get each person from a multiple choice column?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, people-picker, multiple-values

So, the question does a poor job of outlining the problem.

I've got one list where my clients track their projects; let's call it Projects.  In it, they make a selection on a multiple choice column indicating what area of the company their project affects.  The purpose of this is so that when it's time for the project to receive approval, it can be routed to the appropriate approver.

Approvers are linked with the respective areas via another list, which we'll call AreaOwners.

Occasionally, clients will have projects that affect multiple areas.  Multiple areas require multiple approvers.  So, how do I grab multiple names from my AreaOwners list based on multiple selections from the area column.  It'd look like this:

**Projects**

```
ID  Area

1   NOC, LOC
```

**AreaOwners**

```
Area OwnerName

NOC  Jane Doe

LOC  John Doe

POC  Jack Johns
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across your post with no answer, 4 years ago but thought i might be able to put one up for people in the future.

This can be resolved by having SharePoint groups in 'site permission' that puts these people in the group as leaders.

'Area' column in the 'projects' list may selected through the column type 'persons or group'

But the issue i am having is how to limit this persons and group column type to a choice only so that one does not need to go type the full name of the group in.

yep.
Figuring that one out and i'll update it here if i ever have an answer.